# Creating new column based on multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create categories based on multiple columns in pandas but it is taking forever to run so i'm not sure it is correct. I left for 30 mns and was still running so stopped it. I'm trying to create a new column based on several other columns (in my actual data it is about 15 cols). However when I try on a smaller dataset it is very quick. Any suggestions?

```
other_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']


def labels(row):
    if ((row['col 6'] > 1) & (row[other_cols] < 1)).all():
        return 'Yes'
    if ((row['col 6'] >1) & (row['col 7'] >1) & (row[other_cols] <1)).all():
        return 'Maybe'
    if ((row['col 6'] <1) & (row['col 7']>1) & (row[other_cols] <1)).all():
        return 'no'

df['category'] = df.apply(lambda row: labels(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that maybe :

```
ther_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']


def labels(row):
    elif ((row['col 6'] > 1) & (row[other_cols] < 1)).all():
        row['category'] = 'Yes'
    elif ((row['col 6'] >1) & (row['col 7'] >1) & (row[other_cols] <1)).all():
        row['category'] = 'Maybe'
    elif ((row['col 6'] <1) & (row['col 7']>1) & (row[other_cols] <1)).all():
        row['category'] = 'no'
    else:
        row['category'] = ''

df = df.apply(labels, axis=1)
```

What is the size of your dataset ?

I'm sorry i can not comment I am still new here

Comment: Why would this be quicker? Just curious to know as I am a beginner myself. The data contains about 15,000 rows and 20 columns